# Prevent wi-fi to turn off when laptop's lid is closed

Tags: wireless, internet, power-management

even though I set in the settings when the laptop is on AC to do nothing when the lid is closed, I also selected on `gnome-tweak-tool` to not suspend but, the wireless still turns off.

How can I make the Wi-Fi working with the lid closed, on AC? I'm on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool missing in the default setup named GNOME Tweaks. This option sets the one you want to disable. The suspend is what kills the wifi.

[image]

Command line method:

Do nothing when on battery:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action blank
```

Do nothing when on power:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action blank
```

Comment: I did the same thing on Ubuntu 17.10 and looks like after I open the laptop's lid, everything is freezing but i can still hear audio